# How come my first blog post and my home page have the same title?

Tags: title, description

I am putting together a new blog and for some reason the home page took the title and description of the initial post. Is there a way to just set the home page title/description separately?

I am trying to edit it via YoastSEO, but I get this screen when I try to set my Home title/description:

[image]

But what I was expecting was the form fields for title/description.

Thank you!

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: @MarkDavidson Right now I am using the basic TwentyThirteen theme. I think it is standard with latest Wordpress

Comment: [TwentyThirteen theme](http://twentythirteendemo.wordpress.com/) doesn't have such a feature. It could be an SEO plugin. Please deactivate all the plugins and see, if this thing still persists.

Comment: This happens with custom themes also that the Blog Page title will take the title of the latest post.

Comment: I added YoastSEO plugin. Is there a way to set things through that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Reading Settings" at a domain's wp-admin/options-reading.php is, by default, set to latest posts. So, WordPress, by default, would show the title of the post being set at "General Settings" at a domain's wp-admin/options-general.php . In this case, Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin would have form fields to customize it.

When the "Reading Settings" are changed to show a [static page as the front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), then the title of that page is shown as the title of the blog itself. This is the expected default behavior. Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin would have not any form fields, in this case, but would contain the link to the post to edit the title and the description.

Comment: thank you. I just tried to set the settings --> reading to discplay static page. But the only option there is the "about us" page. How would I be able to set the home page to the front page?

Comment: The article linked in my answer, may explain better about how these settings work in general.