# Why doesn't YoastSEO allow me to set the title/description for the home page?

Tags: title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, description

For some reason, YoastSEO set my home page to the first blog post. So the home page canonical, title, and description are set to the values of the first blog post.

And when I tried to set the home page's title/description, I got this screen instead of the form fields to set the values of the title/description:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come my first blog post and my home page have the same title?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112714/how-come-my-first-blog-post-and-my-home-page-have-the-same-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Settings > Reading. If you have a Posts/Front page page set, you'll need to add the meta title/description on those particular pages.

Comment: thank you. When I go to settings --> readings and try to set the front page as static page, the only option is give me is the about-us page. Is there a way to set the default page as the static default page from there?

Comment: You will have to create a page that you want to be the homepage, then assign it.

Comment: thank you. But in theory, the home page is already created, right? It is my index.php page. How can I just set that as the home page?

Comment: In Settings > Reading, change Front Page displays to "Latest Posts". That'll cause the homepage to be generated from index.php. Also, you "should" then be able to set the meta title/desc on the Yoast page in your screenshot.

Comment: you know, now for some reason, it started allowing me to set the title/description :) Not sure what was the difference, but thank you :)

Comment: Yep. See my updated comment above. Yoast provides those fields only if there isn't an actual page assigned to the front page for you to add metadata to. Glad I could help!

Comment: "*But in theory, the home page is already created, right? It is my index.php page.*" - **Not true**. The `index.php` template file is the *default fallback template* in the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). WordPress Themes do not define *pages*; rather, Themes define *template files* that WordPress *uses* to render *pages*. Pages can only be created by the *user*.